# How to merge with only the commits contained in the git branch

Tags: git, svn, version-control, merge

We are currently migrating from svn to git, we use a trunk based workflow in svn.

We are having two git branches, master develop and release. Develop and Release are branches off master. We wan't to create a feature branch from develop and after we are done merge it back to develop via a pull request. QA does all the testing on the develop branch. After the QA gives approval we wan't to merge the feature branch off develop into the release branch. Now the issue here is that if there were 10 previous features merged into develop BEFORE we created this feature branch then all those 10 features' commits will also be included in the merge request.

What we wan't to know is how to merge ONLY the commits in the FEATURE BRANCH into the release branch.

We looked at git flow which creates the release branch off develop at the end of the sprint but the problem is that it will include all features merged to develop. In our system we do QA testing on the develop branch and not the individual feature branches, in git flow your supposed to test first each feature branch individually to avoid premature integration and reduce reverts. We might be able to use that but the thing is that we cannot have the resources of setting up servers for all of our features to be tested (server/deployment per feature)

A basic idea of what is happening now with our svn existing workflow

We have two branches, trunk and staging. We start our work on trunk, after we have finished our feature we commit our work to trunk. Afterwords we get a release done for the trunk branch to the QA environment. The QA tests that feature, after we get an OK from the QA we merge our feature to the staging branch. To do this we select the required revisions from trunk and merge them to the staging branch. The QA then does another final regression test. At the end of our sprint we do a build from staging to production and demo environments.

Does anyone know how we could use two branches develop and release and create feature branches from develop and only merge the feature branches changes to the release branch. This is as we can only have two test environments per each branch. Note that this app does not have any unit tests either.

**To Alexander Polomodov**

**EDIT UPDATE 1**

Thanks for your insight. I added this to the main post since the comment size was not enough. Ironically this is what we are trying out initially but didn't find it to meet our needs. The primary reason being that whenever we create a feature branch off release, if there is a conflict it will be only detected when tried to be merged to the develop branch. This is as we are starting our local development without the changes of other people. Now let's say I fixed the merge conflict, for now let's say in the feature branch itself (there is a problem of where I fix it, more on this a bit later). Then after QA is passed and gives me the OK, I merge my branch into release. **Now however I get another conflict**, why? Due to the fact that I simply resolved a merged conflict to match the develop branch and now the other person's code that caused this conflict is not going live. If we were to create a feature branch off develop and when we submit a merge request from develop to release IF the commits in the branch only were taken somehow, then the only problem remaining would be fixing the any merge conflicts ONCE on the release branch. And since we create the feature branch off develop everyone would be working with other peoples code.

**EDIT UPDATE 2**

I tried the second method but couldn't make it work, in theory that is what I wanted to do. I created some sample steps I used.

```
#create the repository    
git init 

#create the initial java source
mkdir src 
gedit src/Test.java 

#add and commit the code to the repository in master
git add src
git commit 

#create the release branch from master
git checkout -b release 

#create the develop branch from master
git checkout master
git checkout -b develop 

#create the feature1 branch from develop
git checkout -b feature1 
gedit src/Test.java #add another method
git add src/
git commit

#merge the feature1 to develop
git checkout develop
git merge feature1

#create the feature2 branch from develop after the merge
git checkout -b feature2 
gedit src/Test.java #add another method
git add src/
git commit

#merge the feature2 to develop
git checkout develop
git merge feature2

#create a branch for rebasing the feature2
git checkout feature2
git checkout -b feature2release 
git rebase release
```

In the above I create a master and two branches develop and release off of it. Afterwards I then proceed to create feature branches off develop and commit to them and merge them back into develop. Each feature simply adds a new java method to the code. Now I want to merge only the method introduced in feature 2 to release while ignoring any other commits made to develop (in this case just the method introduced by feature 1). Now to do this I create a feature2release branch and then rebase that with release. However when I do this I get the following message.

```
Current branch feature2release is up to date.
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong or how instead I should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question right I can suggest a solution. But before I say several words about my perception of your problem:

- Your `develop` branch is rather volatile, and your QA run tests on this branch
- Your `release` branch is rather stable, and you deploy it to your production contour
- You need to create feature branches (i.e `feature1`, `feature2`, `feature3`) but merge it to `develop` branch for qa-tests
- You need to include only some feature branches (not all merged to developed) into your next release

If it's all true you can:

- Create each feature branch (`feature1`, `feature2`, `feature3`) from stable `release` branch
- Merge each ready feature branch to `develop` for tests
- If this feature branch fails all fixes should be done in its branch and not `develop` branch
- When feature is ready its branch also is ready for merging to release
- When the time of the next release, you choose only desired branches and merge it to release

There are some significant drawbacks in this approach but these disadvantages are related to functional intersection developed in different feature branches. Your qa-tests on develop branch is vulnerable to [false positives and false negatives errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives) in finding bugs.

I've added some explanation drawing:
[image]

**Another workflow for edited part of question**

- Create each feature branch (`feature1`, `feature2`, `feature3`) from unstable `develop` branch with changes of other people
- Merge each ready feature branch to `develop` for tests
- If this feature branch fails all fixes should be done in its branch and not `develop` branch
- When feature is ready its branch also is ready create branch feature1-for-release for merging to release with this steps

  `git branch feature1-for-release feature1 # create branch for release
  git chekcout feature1-for-release # checkout to this branch
  git rebase release # rebase from master`
- When the time of the next release, you choose only desired branches (i.e feature1-for-release) and merge it to release

There are some significant drawbacks in this approach and firstly you never ever run tests on this particular rebased branches. And this is a problem. I can give a simple example:

- You start your branch `feature1` from develop with merged branch `feature0` with some functionality
- You use this functionality from `feature0` and create some new feature
- Your `feature1` has been passed qa-tests and you create `feature1-for-release` branch
- Assume that you decide to add to next release `feature1-for-release` branch but not `feature0-for-release` branch
- Your `release` will be deployed with non-working functionality from `feature1` task because it depends on `feature0` which is absent in this release

**Update for another workflow for edited part of question**

I follow steps of **Edit update 2** and get the same results. 
Test.java in master has one line:

```
// initial
```

Test.java in feature1 has two lines:

```
// initial
// feature1
```

Test.java in feature2 has 3 lines:

```
// initial
// feature1
// feature2
```

And it puts the end to the use of such a scheme. I think now I can explain why:

- rebase is a method to apply your difference on the top of the changes from another branch
- so there is no changes in `release` branch and you get `feature2release is up to date`
- it's my fault, I rarely use complicated `rebase` (usually only for squash commits, and changes in message for commits) so I forgot about this in my logical construction for alternative scheme

Also I try to create feature2releaseV2 branch using combination of git apply + git diff in for of:

- create branch feature2releaseV2 from release
- apply diff between start and finish of creating feature2
- but I get this errors:

  `# b1d49dd - end of feature2, #78d0839 - start of feature2
  $ git diff b1d49dd 78d0839 | git apply -v 
  Checking patch src/Test.java...
  error: while searching for:
  // initial
  // feature1
  // feature2`

Also I try to create feature2releaseV3 branch using cherry-picking but get conflicts which are very hard to resolve:

```
$ git status
On branch feature2releaseV2
You are currently cherry-picking commit b1d49dd.
  (fix conflicts and run "git cherry-pick --continue")
  (use "git cherry-pick --abort" to cancel the cherry-pick operation)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

    both modified:   src/Test.java

$ git diff
diff --cc src/Test.java
index 348ec50,9a56d40..0000000
--- a/src/Test.java
+++ b/src/Test.java
@@@ -1,1 -1,3 +1,7 @@@
- // initial
++<<<<<<< HEAD
++// initial
++=======
+ // initial
+ // feature1
 -// feature2
++// feature2
++>>>>>>> b1d49dd... feature2
```

As a result, I have one piece of advice:

It's necessarily to create releases more often and in this case every developer can start new feature branch from stable release version. For example we deploy our system once or twice per day and starts our feature branches from release version.

Comment: I updated the main post with a reply to your answer as the comment section was not long enough, please have a look.

Comment: Was wondering what if I created a feature branch off develop and rebased that feature branch to release?.

Comment: I've add some thoughts about using rebasing, see carefully drawbacks of this approach and example with dependencies on non-released branches which is already in develop

Comment: Just to confirm, the drawback you described would be present in a trunk based workflow yes where we merged our revisions of items from trunk to the release branch. For example I am working on trunk and my feature (feature 2) depends on feature 1. So when I merge my revisions from trunk to the release branch in svn I get a compile error because the dependencies in feature 1 are not present correct?

Comment: It depends on your stack of technology. If you compile your program, compiler maybe find problem. But it will not work if you use interpreted languages. Also your `feature1` can modify some base business logic and `feature2` depends not only on existence of code but also on this modifications. If so, even compilers will not find this subtle dependency

Comment: I tried doing the second method on a fresh new local repository however I was unable to successfully merge only the commits based on a feature branch to the release branch. I have added the list of steps I used to try this out, please have a look.

Comment: I check your updated question and you are right, rebase is not working as you need for this case, I also try to get only needed changes with  `git diff` + `git apply` but it doesn't work too, and `git cherry-pick` doesn't help you because of hard conflicts. You should to create release more often and in this case you can use your first schema. For example we deploy our system once or twice per day and starts our branch from release version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106439/discussion-between-milindad-and-alexander-polomodov).